# How to test difference between two subgroups in one sample - how to decide about normality in the subgroups?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution

I distributed one questionnaire to a group of 191 respondents (Questions on Likert scale). I split the sample into men a women. I would like to see, if the difference between them is significatn (if any).
My proceedure - might be absolutely wrong:

1. test normality to be able to decide, what test to use to compare these two groups (in case of normality parametric t-test, or in case of non-normal distribution non-parametric Mann-Whitney Utest). And here I got stuck:
   I was trying to see, if the variable is normally distributed. According to the literature, I should use neither Shapiro-Wilk (the sample has more than 50 respondents) and nor Kolmogorov-Smirnov (the sample is over 100). I apllied both anyway, and I got different results (one K-S says they are normal, S-W says no). Therefore, I tried to look for other solution:
   I found that "for medium-sized samples (50 < n < 300), reject the null hypothesis at absolute z-value over 3.29, which corresponds with an alpha level 0.05, and conclude the distribution of the sample is non-normal". In my sample, calculating z-scores (as division of skewness and its standard error) are off the interval -3,29; 3,29, therefore, the distribution should not be normal. I do not understand, what this criteria really do and why they are like this either.

At the same time, I was told, that the scewness is good for deciding the normality in a sample of my size. Its values fall in the interval <-1;1>, and therefore, the distribution should be considered normal... I do not know, where this assumption comes from, but many researches in psychology use it.
Then, I looked at the Q-Q- plots and the Histograms, but I may try as much as I can, but I do not see anything on these graphs...
K-S: 0,076  0,139
S-W: 0,970 0,013
[[image: histogram and Q-Q plot1]
[image]

Please advice, what to do... My goal is to find out if there is a statistically significant difference between raw scores of subgroups in my group (they had the same questionnaire).
Thank for any advice

Comment: A t-test will work fine for these data.  In fact, a Z-test will be OK, too.

Comment: If the t-test confirms significance of difference, do I need to find the effect size  with Hedges G? (the samples have different sizes)? I compared the score in one test in men and women (not the effect if something).

Comment: The point of the t-test is to assess a difference in means: so report and interpret your estimate of that difference.